# Use Ctrl+Backspace to delete word in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, command-line

How could I erase the whole word with using Ctrl-Backspace in Windows XP command line? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 9):

CMD or Powershell doesn't have a native shortcut to delete the word to the left or right. Here are some [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Command_line_shortcuts) of what each platform can do.
What you could probably do to make it a little easier is use the shortcut to move to the beginning or end of a word and start deleting or backspacing to delete the word.

Comment: I'm not sure this is accurate anymore. CTRL+Backspace deletes the last word in Powershell on Win10.

Answer (score 8):

[AHK](http://autohotkey.com) Code to replicate Ctrl+Backspace functionality to delete previous word. What this does is selects the previous word with Ctrl+Shift+Left, and then presses delete. Works well enough for me in notepad, and other programs, though is bit wonky in win7. Can't confirm for terminal right now.

```
^BackSpace:: ;;Delete previous word
    Send ^+{Left}{Del}
 Return
```

Answer (score 5):

try this instead:

```
^BackSpace:: ;;Delete previous word
Send ^+{Left}
Loop, 500 {
    Send {Del}
}
Return
```

it modified the previous answer by sending 500 deletes after positioning at the previous word.  500 may be excessive, but so what.

this is for autohotkey (http://www.autohotkey.com/) and works in a cmd window, I put it in my cmd window specific section with the paste code like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
; Paste in command window
^V::
Send !{Space}ep
return

^BackSpace:: ;;Delete previous word
Send ^+{Left}
Loop, 500 {
    Send {Del}
}
Return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: What if the cursor was in the middle of a line and there are more words following the previous word?

Answer (score 5):

Been wanting this a long time! :) Just wanted to +1 idea of using AHK, and suggest an improvement to the script for it. I like ^W for word erase, as in linux shells, so I'm glad to have found this.

The first script didn't work for me in CMD (jumps back a word then erases the first character, not the whole word). The next script above wasn't quite ideal either, so rather than looping e.g. 500 times sending Del keystrokes (which I found sometimes spills over and sends deletes into another window if you change focus, eek), instead there is CMD's F4 functionality: Prompts for a character and deletes up to that char. So, jump a word back with ctrl-Left, then F4 followed by Space, to delete up to a space. The only minor downsides are that (a) it flashes the prompt box briefly, and (b) repeated word erases leave a pile of spaces (harmless but a bit unattractive). I also wanted ^U (erase to start of line) and ^A/^E/^F/^B word/char movement like linux shells (even though they already exist in CMD, I touch type so prefer not to move my hands away from the main keyboard). :) I also kept in David Hoppe's great ^V for paste.

Thus:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
; Paste in command window
^V::
Send !{Space}ep
return

; was ^BackSpace, I prefer ^W a la linux
^W:: ;;Delete previous word
Send ^+{Left}
Send {F4}{Space}
Return

^U::   ;;erase to start of line
Send ^{Home}
Return

^A::   ;;move to start of line
Send {Home}
Return

^E::   ;;move to end of line
Send {End}
Return

^F::   ;; move one char forward
Send {Right}
Return

^B::   ;;move one char back
Send {Left}
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 3):

In Powershell

[image: word]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) highlights a word backwards.

[image: Word selected]

Then press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the last word.

[image: Deleting selected word]

In windows command prompt

[image: Word]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd>  (press left arrow twice to select the last word)

[image: Word selected]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Bakspace</kbd> to delete the last word

[image: Delete last word]

Comment: This doesn't work, hence down-voted.

Comment: In windows 10 powershell and command prompt it works fine

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible natively in the Windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using conemu (or cmder) you can add this macro and it will delete the word with `ctrl+backspace`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to select more <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, because it can select the backspace after/before the word.

For example, in AutoHotkey:

```
^w:: ;;Delete previous word
    Send ^+{Left}+{Left}
    Loop, 5 {
        Send {Del}
    }
Return
!d:: ;; Delete backward word
    Send ^+{Right}+{Rigt}
    Loop, 5 {
        Send {Backspace}
    }
Return
```